# MongoDB grouping performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, grouping, aggregation-framework, indices

I have large mongodb collection (about 24 mil. documents).
The collection may contain multiple versions of one document with different `timestamp` field.

Sometimes I need to get the list of all latest versions of documents so I use aggregation pipeline, especially `$group` to achieve this task.
I just want to group by the key and get `$last` for every field of the document.

But MongoDB `$group` does not use indices, therefore operation takes A LOT of time.
Documentation says that `$group` should be used after `$match` or `$sort` but this is not my case - I need to aggregate the whole collection.

Is there any way to group documents in mongodb using indices? Or maybe any other proper way to do similar aggregations?

MapReduce doesn't seem to be very fast.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're only interested in the most recent version of each document. I'm not sure if it's possible to use an index with your current document scheme. You could add a "most recent" flag to each document that you update every time you add a new document. Then your `$match` would just look for `most_recent: true`, no need to use `$group` with `$last` to get the most recent.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, however we tend to not touch existing records when inserting a new one. Anyway, thanks! We'll use it as a fallback plan :)